# Using Docker to set up an Elasticsearch cluster across multiple machines

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have currently tried to use docker-compose to spin up multiple elasticsearch containers but these are all deployed on my local machine. What would be the process for deploying multiple containers to several different machines using Docker?

I know that docker swarm exists but I am not sure how to utilize it along with docker compose so that I spin up multiple elasticsearch nodes that are located in the difference virtual machines that I have spun up.

So far I know that in the `elasticsearch.yml` config file I need to specify the virtual machine addresses with 
`discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["vm_ip1:9200", "vm_ip2:9200"]` but I am not sure how to enforce this change onto the docker containers that are created. To spin up the containers I used the sample docker-compose.yml file that is shown in the elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-prod-cluster-composefile)

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elasticsearchr
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
      - "index.number_of_shards: 2"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
```

Please let me know if any more details are needed, thanks!